# Melhor forma de fazer uma Action que não retorna dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo uma chamada ajax para alterar um objeto. A chamada não precisa retornar nada. Apenas o código http 200 (OK) ou 500 (erro).
Estou usando o seguinte código na action mas não sei se é o melhor:

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma Action que não retorna dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É usando `ActionResult` mesmo. O problema é que `EmptyResult` não retorna nada **mesmo**, nem código de requisição:

```
public ActionResult MinhaActionSucesso()
{    
   // Antes do MVC5
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);

   // MVC5+
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

public ActionResult MinhaActionErroInterno()
{    
   // Antes do MVC5
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);

   // MVC5+
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

[Veja mais sobre as enumerações `HttpStatusCode` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[Veja mais sobre o `HttpStatusCodeResult` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Para o ASP.NET MVC o `EmptyResult` funciona bem. Mas se a a função da sua ação é só ser chamada por AJAX (i.e., basicamente uma API), então você também pode usar o um ApiController (ASP.NET Web API), e na sua ação você retorna `this.Ok()` ou `this.InternalServerError()` (o tipo de retorno do método seria `IHttpActionResult`), deixando mais clara a sua intenção:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        if (algumaCondicaoBoa)
        {
            return this.Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```